# Testing for stdout in Python Unit Test

Tags: python, unit-testing, while-loop, stdout

Hey everyone so for the past week, I've been practicing unit testing with different types of scenarios. I see the importance in Unit testing and want to get as familiar with them as possible. Below is a basic countdown timer. I want to test for the output that is displayed after the While Loop. Here is the code I'm trying to test.

```
Timer = 11

while Timer > 0:
    Timer = Timer - 1
    print(Timer)

print("Times Up!")
```

Here's my test suite that I used for a simple Hello World program, but it didn't work. I'm assuming because of the outputs i have going on within the while loop. So how would I test for just the "Times Up!"

```
import unittest
import sys
import io

from PopListTestView4 import *

class UnitTest(unittest.TestCase):


    def test_Output(self):

        saved_stdout = sys.stdout
            try:
                out = io.StringIO()
                sys.stdout = out
                output = out.getvalue().strip()
                assert output == 'Times up!'
            finally:
                sys.stdout = saved_stdout


if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(UnitTest)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assert output.endswith('Times up!')`

`str.endswith` in the Python documentation : https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitor, when you add some explanation to your intension.